# Camel Delete File Exception

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

When I am trying to process a file in Camel and it fails I try to move the file to an error directory but get the following error message:

**org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot delete file:....**

I don't know if Windows is locking the file, but I have closed any streams that may cause this to occur on my side. If this is Windows what could I do to release this lock?

The route is a simple `from()... process().. to()` and there are some headers set after the `process()`  It is the `to()` where this fails and the file does not move into the error directory as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) or processexplorer to see open handles. You may able to make a guess then.

Comment: I can see that the file is showing in there and it is locked by my Java process. Sometimes it disappears and I don't have the problem, other times it doesn't so then it can't be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there was a rogue stream that needed changing. I found this out using **Process Explorer** as it identified the same file twice. One lock was removed and another was not and from this I found an open stream that wasn't handled in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it has something to do with [this](http://camel.apache.org/file.html):

> **Cannot move/delete file after processing on Windows**
>
> There is a potential issue on Windows platform with Camel 1.5.x. That
>   it cannot move or delete the file after processing. You should get an
>   exception thrown.
>
> The workaround is to convert the body to a String after consuming
>   using convertBodyTo: eg
>   from("file://inbox").convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file://outbox");.
>
> There should be a fix in Camel 1.6.0 to remedy this, but we would like
>   to get feedback on this issue. So if you are on Windows please give it
>   a go.

Comment: I am running Camel 2.13.0 so this shouldn't be a problem now as it was fixed in 1.6.0.